# How can I get the url of "src=..."?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to loop through all the **img** classes here but I am not sure how I can get the *src=* link

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://giphy.com/search/anxiety'
html = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
gifs = soup.findAll("img", attrs={"class": "giphy-gif-img"})

for gif in gifs:
    print(gif.get('image-src'))
```

Comment: the GIFs are loaded dynamically in separate requests (by your browser). a better approach would be to use the API: https://developers.giphy.com/docs/api#quick-start-guide

Answer (score 1):

In your last line, you can use `gif.get('src')`.
However, `gifs` is empty since there are no images with `class=giphy-gif-img` on the page.